# How to combine start date and end date in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a graph with panadas. I am able to plot the graph, but in the x-axis instead of the date, I would like date range(ie, start date - end date). For eg, instead of 2022-08-5 I want to show 2022-08-15 - 2022-08-21 and instead of 2022-09-01 I want to show 2022-09-01 - 2022-09-06

Here is the code I have for the same,

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime("2022" + df['WeekNumber'].astype(str) + "1",  format='%G%V%w')
df['EndDate'] = df['StartDate'] + pd.offsets.Week(weekday=6)
df = df.set_index("StartDate").drop(columns=["EndDate", "WeekNumber"])
df.plot(kind="line", legend=False, xlabel="Date", ylabel="hrs")
```

I am only using  df['StartDate']  for  below graph, how can I use `df['StartDate'] + '-' + df['EndDate']` instead?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `xticks` while making sure to convert to the right date format using `strftime`:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({"WeekNumber": [33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43], "hrs": [82, 100, 55, 100, 100, 100, 100, 97, 99, 71, 80]})

df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime("2022" + df['WeekNumber'].astype(str) + "1",  format='%G%V%w')
df['EndDate'] = df['StartDate'] + pd.offsets.Week(weekday=6)

df = df.set_index("StartDate").drop(columns=["EndDate", "WeekNumber"])

df.plot(y="hrs", kind="line", legend=False, xlabel="Date", ylabel="hrs")

start_dates = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
end_dates = (df.index + pd.offsets.Week(weekday=6)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
plt.xticks(df.index, start_dates + ' - ' + end_dates, rotation=40)

plt.show()
```